# How to use jdk8 to group by and filter the ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Here is a Object call Mon. It has two attrs, start and end, both are String.
The end attr can include ";" like this

```
Mon m1 = new Mon(); m1.setStart("A"); m1.setEnd("a;b");
Mon m2 = new Mon(); m2.setStart("A"); m2.setEnd("b");
Mon m3 = new Mon(); m3.setStart("C"); m3.setEnd("c");
Mon m4 = new Mon(); m4.setStart("A"); m4.setEnd("c");
```

And here is a ArrayList.

```
List<Mon> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(m1);list.add(m2);list.add(m3);list.add(m4);
```

Now I want to group the list by the start attr and the end attr, but base on the end contains ";", so also I want to put the m1 and m2 into a same group because the m1.end contains the m2.end, but the m4 is in another group as m4 start and end is not same as m1,m2.

I tried to use Collectors.groupingBy to group by the start

```
Map<String, List<Mon>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getStart()));
```

But it is not the result what i want
Output like this:

```
key: Aa;b OR Ab , value: m1, m2
key: Cc, value: m3
key: Ac, value: m4
```

Is any way to implement it, also the jdk8 stream function is better

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you explain, what do you mean by group

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ShaileshChandra I mean group the list by the start attr, just like this `Map<String, List<Mon>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getStartMsgType()));`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I tried to use Collectors.groupingBy, but i can only group the start attr, don't know how to check the end attr as it contains ";"

Comment: why do you need to check for end attribute. I don't see any point of doing that? Just groupingBy start gives the desired result afaiu.

Comment: m1 and m2 has the same start attribute, hence put in the same group despite their end attribute.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala but what i want is put the m1 and m2 into the same group be as not only the same start attr, also the end attr has the same part. do you know what i mean

Comment: I updated the question and the output above

Comment: Dear Gentle, I am not able to understand grouping pattern of your input and output. Do you want to make key by concatenating getStart() and getEnd()? Id yes, why don't we have entry with key Ab? Also your query states that you want to group by getStart() only. Can you fix your question please

Comment: `new ArrayList()` — **Never use raw types**. Just don't. Write `new ArrayList<>()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should provide you expected outcome..

```
Mon m1 = new Mon(); m1.setStart("A"); m1.setEnd("a;b");
Mon m2 = new Mon(); m2.setStart("A"); m2.setEnd("b");
Mon m3 = new Mon(); m3.setStart("C"); m3.setEnd("c");

List<Mon> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(m1);list.add(m2);list.add(m3);

Function<Mon, String> compositeKey = mon -> mon.getStart()+mon.getEnd();

Map<String, List<Mon>> resultMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositeKey,Collectors.toList()));
```

*NOTE :* For your char level match in key, you will have to write a lambda expression in `list.stream().forEach(){ mon ->....` I dont think that complex a requirement can not be fixed by OOB functions. Even Hashmap functions are based on exact key match. And if I see your expected outcome, that is not even a contains match `key: Aa;b OR Ab`

```
final Map<String, List<Mon>> resultMap = new HashMap();
list.stream().forEach(mon -> {
     resultMap.put(mon.getStart()+getEnd(), ....);
});
```

Good Luck but to be frank this is a weired implementation where you want to apply char matched in a Map key. Not sure what objective you are trying to achieve with it.

Comment: i updated the question and output above, could you advise?

Comment: Dear Gentle, I am not able to understand grouping pattern of your input and output. Do you want to make key by `concatenating getStart() and getEnd()`? Id yes, why don't we have entry with key `Ab`? Also your query statement still that you want to group by getStart() only but your expected output doesn't support it.  Can you fix your question please

Comment: i updated the question and output above, could you advise? And if we want the key Ab, how could we do that?

Comment: Changed it for your updated query. Check if it works. Haven't tested it.

Comment: Which package does StringUtils comes from?

Comment: Its in apache commons liberary. You can simply replace by concat or getStart()+getEnd().

Comment: seems cannot work.```Function<Mon, String> compositeKey = mon -> mon.getStart().concat(mon.getEnd());

  Map<String, List<Mon>> resultMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositeKey,Collectors.toList()));

  
   
  for(Entry<String, List<Mon>> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + entry.getValue().size());
  }``` result is ```Cc1
Aa1
Ac1
Aa;b1
```

Comment: That is because when you connect string1+string2 as key, there are 4 unique combinations

Comment: Add one more `Mon m5 = new Mon(); m5.setStart("A"); m5.setEnd("a;b");` and test. This will make two objects with same key i.e., m1 and m5 and hence you should get 2 count against it

Comment: but what i want is put the m1 and m2 into the same combinations because m1.end contains m2.end

Comment: For that you will have to write a lambda expression in stream().forEach().... I am sure that complex a requirement can not be fixed by OOB functions. Even Hashmap functions are based on exact key match. And if I see your expected outcome, that is not even a contains match `key: Aa;b OR Ab`

Comment: so you mean to i have to loop the HashMap? do you have any example or info? Thanks a lot

Comment: Add a small note to answer, you would need to take it forward from here :-) Good Luck but to be frank this is a weired implementation where you want to apply char matched in a Map key. Not sure what objective you are trying to achieve with it.

Comment: [“*Its in apache commons liberary. You can simply replace by concat or getStart()+getEnd()*”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653781/how-to-use-jdk8-to-group-by-and-filter-the-arraylistobject#comment103615105_58654042) Then, why don’t you use `getStart()+getEnd()` instead of introducing an unnecessary use of a 3d party library? It’s not like `StringUtils.join(mon.getStart(), mon.getEnd())` was in any way simpler or easier to understand than `getStart() + getEnd()`…

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Holger. I agree Its nothing simpler or easier but a little verbose offering. Also I used it out of habit of using apache commons for various functions. In both the way it tries to answer author's query. No doubt one can use any of the way. Also if user is curious, they might explore and learn something for future.

Comment: I’m not sure what the OP will learn when you use a 3rd party library function, without even mentioning the library in your answer.

Comment: Dear @Holger - Pleae re-read my comment again `Also, if user is curious, they might explore and learn something for future`. I don't disagree from your perspective, it's a way of looking at it.  And, I accept your feedback, will keep it plain old basic in future. I am a newbie on this forum (a week old only), I don't know the way of doings of experienced like you. Thanks once again for your scrutiny of my answers and comments section too.